# How to copy a file to a new folder with MS Graph SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

If you only have the DriveID and the DriveItemID of the file you are copying and do not know the DriveItemID of the folder you are copying too how would you do the copy with MS Graph SDK in c#?

My code as follows:

```
        public async Task<DriveItem> CopyFileAsync(string DriveID, string DriveItemID,string FileName, string DestFolderDriveItemID)
    {
        DriveItem response = null;
        try
        {
            var parentReference = new ItemReference
            {
                DriveId = DriveID,
                Id = DestFolderDriveItemID
            };

            response = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives[DriveID].Items[DriveItemID]
                .Copy(FileName, parentReference)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error copying file: {ex.ToString()}");
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: If you know the folder name, you can probably get the ID (this works with email folders, I haven't used it with drive folders)

Comment: What do you know about the destination? Only destination drive id? Do you know at least the name of the destination folder? Does the destination folder already exist?

Comment: I know the folder structure but not the ID. I could I guess query for the id I just did not know if I could do it in one request not knowing the ID.